# Problem with showing that a complex function $|f(z)|\leq M$ (estimation lemma)

Tags: complex-analysis

> Problem statement: Let $f:U\subseteq \mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ with $z\mapsto \frac{e^z}{z}$, with the path $\gamma_r:[0,\pi]\to \mathbb{C}$ with $t\mapsto -r(\sin t+i\cos t)$, with $r\geq 0$. Show that $$\left|\int_{\gamma_r}f(z)dz\right|\leq \pi$$

**Attempt:**

Assuming that $f$ is continuous on an open set $U$, with $\gamma_r$ being a picewise curve in $U$. If there is a constant $M\geq 0$ such that $|f(z)|\leq M$ for all points $z\in \gamma_r$ then

$$\left|\int_{\gamma_r}f\right|\leq M\ell(\gamma_r)$$

where $$\ell(\gamma_r)=\int^\pi_0|\gamma_r'(t)|=r\pi$$

But the problem is to show that $|f(\gamma_r(t))|\leq M$.

$$|f(\gamma_r(t))|=\left|\frac{e^{-r\sin t+ir\cos t}}{-r\sin t+ir\cos t}\right|=\frac{|e^{-r\sin t}e^{ir\cos t}|}{r}=\frac{e^{-r\sin t}}{r}\leq \frac{e^{r}}{r}$$

But $0<e^r<\infty$ so it cannot be bounded. I'm pretty sure that I am overlooking something.

Answer (score 2):

Note that $\gamma_r$ is deifned on $[0,\pi]$. So $\sin t \geq 0$ and $e^{-r\sin t} \leq 1$.

Comment: oh wow, I can't believe that I missed that..... Thanks a lot!